# How to make animation go backwards

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have this sketch here:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.block').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: anim .2s;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

@keyframes anim {
    from {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-100%);}
    to {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0);}}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">press me</button>
<div class="block hide"></div>
```

It works as I want, except the fact it hides on the second press.
Therefore, I need to make block be animated as it moves in, but backwards (so it kind of moves away).

How should I do that correctly?

Comment: Do you really need to use animation? for what you are asking you can just use `transition` or `jquery slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the animation reverse when the class is removed it would be easier to use `transition` in CSS to animate the `transform` and `opacity` properties. Then you get the behaviour for free:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

div.hide {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">press me</button>
<div class="block hide"></div>
```